# integrating migs payment gateway with php website

Tags: php, url, payment-gateway, payment

I have to integrate my php website to migs payments gateway, the API provided by client are .asp files(vbscript)

I created a php form

this form contains all the needed data (variables) to pass the gateway.

I need to know , what is the best way to send these data , by session or what.

And when the transaction is succesfully done, how can I return data to success.php to proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please don't save the data in sessions , they expire in a short interval(with in 15mins)
the best way is to store the details in the temporary table before sending the details and after returning to the site we can get the details from the temporary table using the params passed by the payment gateway

for more details [please refer](http://integrate-payment-gateway.blogspot.in/2012/01/migs-payment-gateway-integration-php.html)

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that when clicking the Pay button a javascript function in the .asp file provided by the client should be executed, this function takes care of securityy of data sent (RSA).How could I execute in a php file a js function presented in .asp file given by the client